# trying to understand while loop in PHP

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I am trying to run the while loop until it equals to thirty.

```
<?php
      $num1=0;
  $num2=0;
  $sum= $num1 + $num2;

  while($sum=30){
      $num1++;
      $num2++;      
      echo "$sum is equal to 30";      
     }

   ?>
```

Comment: `$sum= $num1 + $num2;` should be  inside the `while` loop or it is going to be a infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `while($sum=30)` to `while($sum<30)`.
Then, the while loop will end after you reached 30. The `echo` then comes after the closing bracket.
Sp your working code will look like this:

```
while( $sum < 30 )
{
  $num1++;
  $num2++;
  $sum = $num1 + $num2;
}
echo "sum is $sum (which is 30)";
```

Comment: your comparison is wrong `echo "$sum is 30";` will print `32 is 30`

Comment: You are right. I'll fix this. Anyway he should check the result later on, too.

Comment: this works, but $sum will be 32 after the last loop cycle (if $num1 and $num2 start with 0) ;) - you enter the loop one last time at $sum == 30, increment both nums and calculate sum again

Comment: I know. In this case it works. But in reality you often work with variales that are more complex than here :)

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating the sum outside the while loop, so inside the loop the `$sum` never changes. You have to calculate the sum inside the loop. also `=` is assignment operator. you must use comparison operator to compare.

```
    $num1=0;
    $num2=0;
    $sum=0; //initilize you sum to 0
    while($sum<30){ // loop while your sum is less than 30
        $sum= $num1 + $num2; //calculate the sum
        $num1++;
        $num2++;
    }
        echo "$sum is equal to 30"; 
?>
```

Reference:[Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: This workds. But why did you change it to less than 30 ($sum<30) ?

Comment: The loop has to continue to calculate the sum till it reaches 30.

Comment: you can use `!=` in your case, but if you start with $num1=1; or $num2=1; you may never hit sum of 30. so in that case `<` helps.

Answer (score 0):

use equality operator  (==) not assignment operator (=)

Answer (score 0):

This loop not ends. $sum ever is 0 !.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num1=0;
$num2=0;
$sum= $num1 + $num2;

$x = 0;
while(!$x && $sum <=30){
   $num1++;
   $num2++;

   $sum= $num1 + $num2;
   if($sum ==30){
      echo $sum." is equal to 30";
      $x = 1;
   }
}
```

Try this! Have a nice day !!